# Is injecting an argument, in a policy handler,  within the unity interception pipeline, permissable?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

So I have pulled my transaction scope into an `aspect/policy`. I want to associate a database connection, just one, with this transaction scope before calling the method (a data access method) in the `pipeline` which will call one or potentially more CRUD related and or nested methods.

I could do this by injecting, as one of the input arguments in the call handler, a database connection which I want to use.  This does, however, add tight coupling  between the attribute and its target method, which is plain naughty.

I could refactor  the data layer to ensure that any nested calls (to the same connection) are un-nested and sequential (ensuring that when using `SQL Server 2008` and a transaction scope  this doesnt escalate to a distribtuted transaction).

Another alternative might be a connection factory which serves up a connection but leaves my business layer agnostic to the underlying connection type. `IDBConnection` could do this. A couple of other thoughts are subclassing TransactionScope (by adding in specific one connection capability to it, which is next to "re"-useless elewhere), A global/static data connection object, which is frowned upon or jsut simply threading through the dataconnection object I want to share amongst the methods I am working with within the transaction.

The rationale behind all of this is that I want a clean way of wrapping a method or set of methods which are reliant upon a single database connection without incurring the wrath of `MSDTC` and to avoid using a static connection object, if at all possible.

Comment: balls, I could just di the connection/context into my repository....

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Steven, with the risk of sounding churlish, the question is pretty explicit, the background is a little meandering but gives you an insight into what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the quesetion, slightly, to make it more explicit.